# JavaScript Progress Bar - Move An Object Along With It

Tags: javascript, css, animation, dom

I am studying the JavaScript progress bar on w3schools an attempting to reformulate the code so that the progress bar moves as the percentage increases, but a little round button with the id "progress-flag" moves as well. My code is not working and I've tried several things. Thank you.

```

```
function showProgressByPercent() {
  var bar = document.getElementById("progress-bar");
  var flag = document.getElementById("progress-flag");
  var currentPosition = parseInt(flag.style.left);
  var width = 5;
  var arg = setInterval(frame, 50);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(arg);
    } else {
      width++; 
      bar.style.width = width + '%'; 
      flag.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
      flag.style.left = currentPosition * (width + '%') + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

```

What is most interesting is that even when testing to see if the flag element will move at all with more simple commands, it does not.

Trying to avoid using JQuery till I get the hang of JavaScript.

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/b28yh9hd/

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle

Comment: ok i will now! @brk

Comment: @brk added a jsfiddle thanks for the suggestion https://jsfiddle.net/b28yh9hd/

Comment: it is working as expected. Check this https://jsfiddle.net/b28yh9hd/2/. Also change the javascript loading to body

Comment: as @brk said, the code actually works in your fiddle (if you change the javascript load type to body). Which means there may be some other javascript errors preventing your code from running. Check the console for any errors

Comment: You can not add (`width + "%") + "px"` you need to convert width to pixels

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mix width as a string `width + "%"` with an operator `*` that will not work. You need to convert the width to a number representing pixels. I am assuming that the parent node of bar is the size of the progressbar. I use it so I can get the total width of the progress bar and then calculate the position in pixels width `((width / 100) * totalProgressWidth)`.

Also you should not animate on an interval timer, you should use `requestAnimationFrame` whenever you animate anything in the DOM. w3schools really!!!!.

I have changed your code. I still use a interval timer to update the progress but I use requestAnimationFrame to update the DOM.

```
function showProgressByPercent() {
  var bar = document.getElementById("progress-bar");
  // I am guessing that the parent has the fulll width
  var progressTotal = bar.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  var flag = document.getElementById("progress-flag");
  var currentPosition = parseInt(flag.style.left);
  var width = 5;
  var handle = setInterval(frame,50);
  requestAnimationFrame(display);

  function display(){
      bar.style.width = width + '%'; 
      flag.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
      flag.style.left = (progressTotal.left + ((width / 100) * progressTotal.width)) + 'px';
      if(width < 100){
          requestAnimationFrame(display);
      }
  }
  function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
          width = 100;
          clearInterval(handle);
      } else {
          width++; 
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @blindman67. If you do not like w3schools, what resources do you suggest?

Comment: @HannahBanana Sorry in regard to lessons I can not help you there apart from a little advice. Check the publish dates of any online lessons, when it comes to IT 2 years is old and 5 years is out of date. As a referance and general resource https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript is about the best (though not perfect) and a little more human readable than W3C Documents (which MDN keeps uptodate links to)